# Printf is adding newlines in BASH, and I'm not sure how to get rid of them

Tags: bash, printf

I have the following printf statement in my BASH script to show my script's output nicely:

```
printf "%-20s %-25s %-5s %-10s %-20s \n" $hostn $kernl $uptim $owner $team
```

The output from this is the following:

```
Hostname1        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     307   Lastname, Firstname
Team1
Hostname2        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     270   Lastname, Firstname
Team1
Hostname3        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     298   Lastname, Firstname
Team1
Hostname4        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     271   Lastname, Firstname
Team2
```

I'm not sure why the Team is being added to a new line. I've tried adding another field but it does the same thing:

```
printf "%-20s %-25s %-5s %-10s %-20s %s\n" $hostn $kernl $uptim $owner $team "test"

Hostname1        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     307   Lastname, Firstname         Team1
test
Hostname2        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     270   Lastname, Firstname         Team1
test
Hostname3        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     298   Lastname, Firstname         Team1
test
Hostname4        2.6.32.12-0.7-default     271   Lastname, Firstname         Team2
test
```

Where are these newlines coming from? Is my printf formatting incorrect?

Comment: can we see where the values come from - especially `$team`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might also want to try `'%-*s '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always quote your expansions (all of them, unless you have a specific reason for doing otherwise!) when writing shell scripts:

```
printf "%-20s %-25s %-5s %-10s %-20s %s\n" \
       "$hostn" "$kernl" "$uptim" "$owner" "$team" "test"
```

Since your `$owner` can contain whitespace, if you don't quote correctly, the last name can slip over into the `$team` field otherwise -- and the `test` thus shows up as another `%-20s` field meant for the next line's `$hostn`.